# I tried to define a fine-tuned vgg16 object but the error is I'm always using two different graphs

Tags: python, tensorflow

## This is the define part

```py
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape = [None,224,224,3])

tf.reset_default_graph()
vgg = model.vgg16(x)
```

## Part of the fine-tuned vgg16 class

```py
class vgg16:
    def __init__(self, imgs):
        self.parameters = []
        self.imgs = imgs
        self.convlayers()
        self.fc_layers()
```

The error is:

```
ValueError: Tensor("Placeholder:0", shape=(?, 224, 224, 3), dtype=float32) must be from the same graph as Tensor("conv1_1/weights:0", shape=(3, 3, 3, 64), dtype=float32_ref).
```

Comment: Is your issue resolved now ? Else, The error is telling you that there are multiple tensorflow computational graphs, and that you are trying to combine operations from different graphs. Please try without `tf.reset_default_graph()`.  If it doesn't please share complete reproducible code so that i can help you. Thanks !